# Computing cosine.similarity in R gives different results compared to manual?

Tags: r, cosine-similarity

Here are my vectors:

```
lin_acc_mag_mean vel_ang_unc_mag_mean
             <dbl>                <dbl>
1            0.688                0.317


  lin_acc_mag_mean vel_ang_unc_mag_mean
             <dbl>                <dbl>
1             2.94                0.324
```

or for simplicity:

```
a <- c(.688,.317) 
b <- c(2.94, .324)
```

I want to compute `tcR::cosine.similarity`:

```
cosine.similarity(a,b, .do.norm = T) gives me 1.388816
```

If I will do it myself according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity):

```
sum(c(.688,.317) * c(2.94, .324)) / (sqrt(sum(c(.688,.317) ^ 2)) * sqrt(sum(c(2.94, .324) ^ 2)))
```

And I get `0.948604` so what is different here? 
Please advise. I suppose it is the normalization but will be happy for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `tcR` package the `cosine.similarity` function contains the following:

```
function (.alpha, .beta, .do.norm = NA, .laplace = 0) 
{
    .alpha <- check.distribution(.alpha, .do.norm, .laplace)
    .beta <- check.distribution(.beta, .do.norm, .laplace)
    sum(.alpha * .beta)/(sum(.alpha^2) * sum(.beta^2))
}
```

The intervening `check.distribution` calculation returns a vector that sums to 1, but does not appear to be normalized.

I'd recommend using the `cosine` function in the `lsa` package, instead. This one produces the correct value. It also permits calculation of the cosine similarity for a whole matrix of vectors organized in columns. For example, `cosine(cbind(a,b,b,a))` yields the following:

```
         a        b        b        a
a 1.000000 0.948604 0.948604 1.000000
b 0.948604 1.000000 1.000000 0.948604
b 0.948604 1.000000 1.000000 0.948604
a 1.000000 0.948604 0.948604 1.000000
```